# Need Help Understanding Doctrine 2's ArrayCollection::clear()

Tags: doctrine-orm

I just don't really get this part

> Say you clear a collection of tags by
>   calling $post->getTags()->clear(); and
>   then call $post->getTags()->add($tag).
>   This will not recognize tag being
>   already added before and issue two
>   database calls.

What 2 database calls will be issued? Delete all tags of the post then add one? Thats what I'd expect? Or will it be something else?

Comment: That's how it sounds. I'd try it and log the executed SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to call after the clear?

```
$entityManager->flush();
```

If this don't help try to remove one by one in foreach.